# C# Declare variable in lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I want to do a simple lambda expression like this:

```
IList<MyEntity1> list = GetSomeList();

MyEntity1 result = list.SingleOrDefault<MyEntityList>(
    e => GetMyEntity2(e) != null && GetMyEntity2(e).Id != null && GetMyEntity2(e).Id > 0
);
```

That works perfectly, but getting MyEntity2 from MyEntity1 is not so simple so I would like to declare a variable into the lambda expression to save MyEntity2 and use it, instead of calling again and again to GetMyEntity2 method. Is that possible?

*Note:* The code is just an example that reflects my real case.

Thanks!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Well, first off, are you trying to use this in linq to sql / entity framework / other?

If not, then just do this

```
list.SingleOrDefault(e => {
   var entity = GetMyEntity2(e);

   return entity != null && entity.Id != null && entity.Id > 0;
});
```

Comment: Yep, that just what I was looking for, it works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

If you want to use the "query comprehension" syntactic form you can do this:

```
var query = from entity1 in list
            let entity2 = GetMyEntity2(entity1)
            where entity2 != null
            where entity2.Id != null 
            where entity2.Id > 0
            select entity1;
var result = query.SingleOrDefault();
```

Note also that the middle "where" clause might not be necessary. If "entity2.Id" is a nullable int then it will be correctly checked for null by the lifted `>` operator.

Comment: @Eric Lippert didn't knew this syntactic. But I think I see clearer and easier to understand @Darren Kopp solution. Thanks anyway!
About the middle "where" clause, as I said, this was just an example, those aren't the real clauses. But again thanks anyway, didn't knew I could compare int?.

Comment: @Eric - Is there a reason you use multiple wheres instead of a single where with &&?

Comment: @Steven: Just because it looks nice. Incidentally, Jon Skeet has a blog article today about the performance implications of this choice. They are a bit surprising.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `&&` then nested `where` clauses? You can format them to look pretty much the same, they're more expressive ("where x and y" is more expressive than "where x where y") and they result in simpler-to-run code.

Comment: @configurator: I don't see one way as particularly better or worse than the other.

Comment: @configurator if you are doing it on multiple lines in Linq ad the where syntax is nicer as you can add remove clauses easily.

Comment: Since the matter of multiple "where" condition was mentioned and a blog article on the subject (which is interesting on its own), but no links were provided. I'll take the liberty to do so here: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/06/16/linq-to-objects-and-the-performance-of-nested-quot-where-quot-calls.aspx http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359980/proper-linq-where-clauses

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `Select` operator:

```
IList<MyEntity1> list = GetSomeList();

MyEntity1 result = list
    .Select(x => new { Item = x, Entity2 = GetMyEntity2(x) })    
    .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Entity2 != null && x.Entity2.Id != null && x.Entity2.Id > 0);
```

Or, since you're not even using the `Item` after pushing it through `GetMyEntity2` you could just have:

```
MyEntity1 result = list
    .Select(x => GetMyEntity2(x))    
    .SingleOrDefault(x => x != null && x.Id != null && x.Id > 0);
```

Comment: Thanks @Kirk Woll, but I found easer @Darren Kopp solution. Does this one have some benefit over the other one?

Comment: @Diego, in your example, not so much.  However, my solution is more general and will work in Linq-To-Sql and such as well.  (at least, it would so long as you're not calling custom methods like `GetMyEntity2`).  It also has the vague benefit of being "purely functional".

Comment: Ok, +1 because I'll have it mind for other cases where the @Darren Kopp solution does not apply, thanks! However for this case I think the answer I was looking for (and simple solution) is @Darren's.