# using Linq with multiple where conditions

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities, oracle10g

I have a class representing a table on database that is defined:

```
public class MyClass{
    public int MyClassId{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;} 
    public string LastNamw{get;set;}
    public DateTime From{get;set;}
    public DateTime To{get;set;}
}
```

On which I want to run some search query against oracle database.

Now the question is :

```
var list = context.MyClass
    .Where(x => x.From>= FromMyDate)
    .Where(x => x.To <= ToMyDate);


var list = context.MyClass
    .Where(x => x.From>= FromMyDate && x.To <= ToMyDate);
```

**Is it better to use multiple rows with where condition or one? And why... please**

As far as I understand, I use multiple where clauses when I want to search on result of the first condition.

Comment: See [Proper Linq where clauses](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6360037/1072626)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will be following John Skeet answer as posted by Vossad01.

[Proper Linq where clauses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359980/proper-linq-where-clauses/6360037#6360037)

Answer (score 11):

It shouldn't matter

You are just creating an Expression tree that is passed to the Oracle Provider and it is the provider's job to create the resultant SQL query. Even though the Expression tree would be slightly different between the two, it should still result in the same sql. I like to use a sql profiler to make sure my linq queries are producing efficient sql.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, EF produces multiple joins for EF 6 if using multiple "where" clauses with **navigation properties**. You can get the queries with [EF Profiler](https://hibernatingrhinos.com/products/efprof). I always check the queries with that amazing tool. If you are using EF 6, I advise you not to trust the results :)