# LINQ: differences between single Where with multiple conditions and consecutive Wheres with single condition

Tags: c#, linq

Is there any disadvantage in concatenating multiple `Where` in LINQ instead of using a single `Where` with multiple conditions?

I'm asking because using multiple `Where` can help to reduce complexity and improve maintainability of my code considerably.

Consider following code, `chargeList` is a `List<Charge>` which is the source of a `BindingSource`:

```
IEnumerable<Charge> matchingCharges = chargeList;
if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(channelAbbr))
    matchingCharges = matchingCharges
        .Where(c => c.ChannelAbbreviation == channelAbbr);
if(deliveryNoteDate.HasValue)
    matchingCharges = matchingCharges
        .Where(c => c.ArrivalAt == deliveryNoteDate.Value);
if(chargeID.HasValue)
    matchingCharges = matchingCharges
        .Where(c => c.ChargeID == chargeID.Value);
```

This concise code will handle all combinations of filter, none,one,two,all.

Otherwise i'd have to use `if-else` and multiple conditions in a single `Where`.

This is the best that comes to my mind:

```
// important to keep code readable:
bool filterChannel = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(channelAbbr);
bool filterDate = deliveryNoteDate.HasValue;
bool filterID = chargeID.HasValue;

if(!filterChannel && !filterDate && !filterID)
{
    // take all 
    matchingCharges = chargeList;
}
else
{
    matchingCharges = chargeList
        .Where(c => 
            filterChannel ? c.ChannelAbbreviation == channelAbbr : true
            && filterDate ? c.ArrivalAt == deliveryNoteDate.Value : true
            && filterID   ? c.ChargeID ==  chargeID.Value : true);
}
```

So what are the differences between both, are they negligible? Does the LINQ provider matter?

Comment: As far I remember multiple Where's is recommended approach

Comment: @VladimirSachek your suggested edit would have been better as a comment (here's the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359980/proper-linq-where-clauses/6360037#6360037)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Semantically, there is no difference in the case of `Where` (contrast `OrderBy`, which needs more care). At the implementation level, it is simply multiple predicates with simple expression trees instead of a single predicate with a complex expression tree; but most engines will cope fine with either.

For what you are doing, multiple `Where` is ideal.

Comment: *instead of a single predicate with a complex expression tree* Note that if you use LINQ to Objects, the predicates of multiple `Where` statements will be combined into a single predicate, and only one `foreach` loop will get invoked, regardless the number of `Where` clauses that are chained together.

Comment: @sloth well, that's a *bit* dependent on what else is going on; but yes, in *many* (by no means all) cases the `Iterator<T>.Where(...)` method will be used to combine them, reducing the loops.

Comment: @sloth can you provide a source for the combining of predicates part?

Comment: @sgarg Sure, take a look [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,165). Calling `Where` on a `WhereEnumerableIterator` (e.g. by combining `Where` calls) will result in a single `Iterator` being used and all predicates simply "combined" with `&&`

Answer (score 12):

I was wondering the same thing. That's why I tried this in my own application.

I have a list with a lot of entries and this is what I tried:

```
//TEST 1
Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
stopWatch.Start();
var hoursLinq = _hourDataSource.Hours
            .Where(hour => hour.Id == profile.Id)
            .Where(hour => hour.DayName.Equals("Maandag"))
            .Where(hour => hour.Day == 1)
            .Select(hour => hour);
stopWatch.Stop();
// Get the elapsed time as a TimeSpan value.
TimeSpan ts1 = stopWatch.Elapsed;

//TEST 2
stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
stopWatch.Start();
var hoursLinq2 = _hourDataSource.Hours
            .Where(hour => hour.Id == profile.Id)
            .Select(hour => hour);

if (hoursLinq2.Count() != 0)
{
    var hoursLinq3 = _hourDataSource.Hours
            .Where(hour => hour.DayName.Equals("Maandag"))
            .Select(hour => hour);

    if (hoursLinq3.Count() != 0)
    {
        var hoursLinq4 = _hourDataSource.Hours
            .Where(hour => hour.Day == 1)
            .Select(hour => hour);
    }
}

stopWatch.Stop();
// Get the elapsed time as a TimeSpan value.
TimeSpan ts2 = stopWatch.Elapsed;

//TEST 3
stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
stopWatch.Start();
var hoursLinq5 = _hourDataSource.Hours
            .Where(hour => hour.Id == profile.Id &&
                            hour.DayName.Equals("Maandag") &&
                            hour.Day == 1)
            .Select(hour => hour);

stopWatch.Stop();
// Get the elapsed time as a TimeSpan value.
TimeSpan ts3 = stopWatch.Elapsed;
```

Each timespan (ts1, ts2, ts3) had such a small difference in elapsed time that I'm pretty sure you can ignore it.

I guess it's personal preference, I like the multiple where's because of it's readability