# Why in LINQ using multiple WHERE predicate is slower the using multiple AND?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, visual-studio

Very often use LINQ to filter object array

I ran a test expression that produces the same result, but as different times, I would like to know the reason for this behavior.

```
public long testTimeOperetionWHERE()
{
    Object[] list = opCoIn.getList();
    System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();


    int i = 0;
    while (i<20000)
    {
        var result = list.Where(o => o.Id>0)
                     .Where(o => o.Import>0)
                     .Where(o => o.OrderConfirm==o.NumberConfirm)
                     .Where(o => o.IdActiveCustomer>100 );
        i++;
    }

    long e = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds; 

    return e;
}
```

The time cost result always varies between 90-80

In this case

```
public long testTimeOperetionAND()
{
    Object[] list = opCoIn.getList();
    System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();


    int i = 0;
    while (i < 20000)
    {
        var result = list.Where(o => o.Id > 0
                                && o.Import > 0
                                && o.OrderConfirm==o.NumberConfirm
                                && o.IdActiveCustomer>100);

        i++;
    }

    long e = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds; 

    return e;
}
```

The time cost is always less than 5

Comment: At no point do you actually execute the query.  All you're measuring is whether it's faster to invoke a method once or to invoke it four times.  I'm not surprised that once is faster.

Comment: IM kinda surprised. I thought LINQ would invoke itself 4 times quicker. stupid LINQ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not even executing this LINQ query. You are just defining it.

If you'd for example use `foreach`, `ToList()` or `Count()` you'd get more meaningful results.

```
while (i < 20000)
{
    var result = list.Where(o => o.Id > 0
                            && o.Import > 0
                            && o.OrderConfirm==o.NumberConfirm
                            && o.IdActiveCustomer>100); // not executed
    int justToExecuteIt = result.Count();               // executed here
    i++;
}
```

There should not be a great difference between consecutive `Where`s and consecutive `&&`.

I have asked a similar question recently: [LINQ: differences between single Where with multiple conditions and consecutive Wheres with single condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23674778/linq-differences-between-single-where-with-multiple-conditions-and-consecutive)

You might also find this question useful to understand the benefits of LINQ's deferred execution: [What are the benefits of a Deferred Execution in LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324033/what-are-the-benefits-of-a-deferred-execution-in-linq)

Comment: I am not sure, just asking. Does the difference between methods depend on whether the provider returns `IQueryable` or `IEnumerable`? In first case, multiple `Where` clauses would just modify the syntax tree, but in second, they would result in additional enumerations of the collection, which might be noticeable. Please correct me if I am wrong.
UPD.:oh, I see that that Marc Gravell answered exactly that question on your link.

Comment: @AndreySarafanov: even in LINQ-To-Objects multiple `Where` won't cause multiple enumerations due to the deferred exection. That's what my question linked above addressed. Btw, why the downvote?

Comment: got it, thanks. The overhead caused by multiple enumerators and delegate invocations would be minor indeed. I am sorry for giving your answer a minus bacause of my wrong understanding of the subject.

Comment: @AndreySarafanov: No problem! But you can undo up/downvotes if you want. Just click it again.

Comment: The questions at the links really helped me, yes. And regarding the downvote, I tried to remove it, but unfortunately "You last voted on this answer 15 mins ago. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited."

Comment: I just cited the message this site showed me when I tried to change my vote. And now that you updated your answer, I am finally able to do it. [More](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94567/you-last-voted-on-this-answer-6-mins-ago-locked-too-short) about it.

Comment: +1, nice explanation Tim, still not sure about the downvote.