# Linq not getting correct value in List

Tags: c#, list, linq

I am getting a list of object with type List
and I want that records form the list which `EventType = "Changed"`     `EventDesc = "Changed"` and `UserName = "zMobile"` But when i try to get the result with my code i am getting only one row multiple times with the same data

```
orderEvent = new List<ECGetOrderResponse.OrderEvent>();
EventType = "Changed";
EventDesc = "Changed";
UserName = "zMobile";
orderEvent = result.Body.Order.OrderEvents.OrderEvent;
query = orderEvent
   .Where(o => o.EventType == EventType)
   .Where(o => o.EventDesc == EventDesc)
   .Where(o=>o.UserName==UserName)
   .ToList();
```

One More thing i want to do in the linq code that is: 
the orderEvent has a property that is Notes. i want to filter only that record in which Notes Last 1 value is 'A'

can you describe what will be the correct format of the Linq statement for my result?

Comment: What do you want your code to do? What does it **actually** do? Can you show us some sample inputs and matching sample outputs?

Comment: Why you initialize the list `orderEvent` twice? That's just confusing and would never avoid a `NullReferenceException`(if that was the reason).

Comment: `orderEvent
 .Where(o => o.EventType == EventType &&  o.EventDesc == EventDesc && o.UserName==UserName && o.Notes.EndsWith("A")
.ToList();`

Comment: Add `.Where(o => o.Notes.EndsWith( "A" ))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> when i try to get the result with my code i am getting only one row
>   multiple times with the same data

With this code it's impossible to get always the same row, so `result.Body.Order.OrderEvents.OrderEvent` already contained these rows before. But you haven't shown what it is so we can't help to fix it.

> i want the `orderEvent` has a property that is `Notes`. In the notes
>   field last 1 character is 'A'

Well, that is easy:

```
query = orderEvent
   .Where(o => o.EventType == EventType)
   .Where(o => o.EventDesc == EventDesc)
   .Where(o => o.UserName  == UserName)
   .Where(o => o.Notes.EndsWith("A", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)) 
   .ToList();
```

Change `StringComparison` accordingly if you don't want to allow `a`.

Comment: I would suggest including all conditions in one where clause, for performance reason.

Comment: @Dmitry: there is no noticeable difference between both approaches so if OP prefers this way i don't want to suggest a different. But i wondered myself some time ago, read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23674778/284240).

Comment: @TimSchmelter, there might be a noticeable performance difference. Can't tell without testing.

Comment: @Jodrell: well, i have posted the link to my question, you can find a test there