# Double or Triple "where" clause in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Code:

```
var list=GetList()
    .where(x=>x.att01=="X")
    .where(x=>x.att02=="Y")
    .where(x=>x.att03=="Z")
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Is that really equal to

```
var list=GetList()
    .where(x=>x.att01=="X" && x.att02=="Y" && x.att03=="Z")
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

I've tested it with simple arrays and it shows they are the same. The latter seems to do the job better.

Comment: Its the same. Its called eliminating code repetition. Put everything under one condition.

Comment: Second approach will be faster, because of looping list only once.

Comment: @Fabio False... The `Enumerable.Where` does some tricks, and auto-compacts multiple `.Where` to a single `.Where`. Look for the `WhereEnumerableIterator<TSource>` class.

Comment: @Carsten I don't see how side effects could change anything. The `x.att02` **won't** be executed in both cases if `x.att01 != "x"`

Comment: @xanatos, what about this [http://stackoverflow.com/a/6360007/1565525](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6360007/1565525) accepted answer then?

Comment: @Fabio I quote from there *it's applying the first predicate to all items first **and the result** (which is narrowed down at this point) **is used for the second predicate** and so on*

Comment: @Fabio you don't need multiple iterations to apply multiple filters. Enumerable doesn't even have to do any tricks. LINQ operations are chained so that during iteration, each filter is applied to the passing *record* of the previous filter. The entire sequence only has to be iterated once

Comment: @Carsten I don't comprehend what you are speaking about... but you can write a small example and show it to me...

Comment: @Carsten No, because you are wrong... so you can show it to me. There is no difference between the two methods... The order and then number of calls to the properties is the same.

Comment: Guys, bear in mind the final function is SingleOrDefault, which implies (potentially) the entire collection to be scanned. The FirstOrDefault would behave better...However, I'm with Fabio: a multiple predicates can't be faster than an inline expression.

Comment: @Carsten You can play with https://ideone.com/QAQZ65

Comment: @xanatos I believe none were discussing about the equivalency, rather the computational efficiency. If your snippet's collection would contain 1M items the two way to iterate were different in terms of time. I think you agree on that!

Comment: @MarioVernari The first method does between 2 and 4 delegate calls for each row, the second one does 1 delegate call. Now... This difference is present, but even for one million rows, I don't think it would be more than a nuisance. He spoke expressly of *simple: add some debuging-output (Console.WriteLine, whatever) to all 3 of your attributes and then watch the order they are called* He is convinced that the "external" where will be executed completely before the second-level where will begin executing. He completely missed how enumerables work.

Comment: @xanatos actually, the only result here is a mess of different things. Carsten pointed the different behavior upon a Where predicate contains something "unusual" (let's think to a query against a DB). Under this context, the two approaches aren't the same. Later, Fabio pointed out the efficiency of the latter approach. I agree: in a pure plain code, there's no substantial difference.

Comment: @xanatos Ahhh, Okay!...Understood. Thank you for the brilliant snippet!

Comment: @xanatos yeah sorry - forgot that it's only implemented on `IEnumerable` for C# :( - so you are right here

Answer (score 5):

Given a "standard" `Enumerable.Where` they are totally equivalent (from the result standpoint). The first one will be converted to the second one by the private class [`WhereEnumerableIterator<TSource>`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,c7d6c8b578f62bef,references), to be exact by this method:

```
public override IEnumerable<TSource> Where(Func<TSource, bool> predicate) {
    return new WhereEnumerableIterator<TSource>(source, CombinePredicates(this.predicate, predicate));
}
```

that will combine the predicates in this way:

```
static Func<TSource, bool> CombinePredicates<TSource>(Func<TSource, bool> predicate1, Func<TSource, bool> predicate2) {
    return x => predicate1(x) && predicate2(x);
}
```

See the `x => predicate1(x) && predicate2(x)`?

Technically the second one will be a little faster, because the first one will have some more delegate calls to do, but unless you are filtering million of rows, the time difference is negligible.

Note that, while the `Enumerable.Where` does funny tricks, even a non-smart `.Where`, like:

```
public static class SimpleEnumerable
{
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> SimpleWhere<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
    {
        foreach (TSource element in source)
        {
            if (predicate(element))
            {
                yield return element;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

would be totally equivalent (but even slower!). See the example here: https://ideone.com/QAQZ65

Answer (score 4):

> I've tested it with simple arrays and it shows they are the same.

Semantically, they both do the same. *In this particular case (current overload being used)*, behind the scenes, the `WhereEnumerableIterator<TSource>` will output a single enumerator with chained predicates:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
                                                  Func<TSource, bool> predicate) 
{
    // This is the important line
    if (source is Iterator<TSource>) 
        return ((Iterator<TSource>)source).Where(predicate);
    if (source is TSource[]) 
        return new WhereArrayIterator<TSource>((TSource[])source, predicate);
    if (source is List<TSource>) 
        return new WhereListIterator<TSource>((List<TSource>)source, predicate);
    return new WhereEnumerableIterator<TSource>(source, predicate);
}
```

The `IEnumerable<TSource>` is actually a previous `WhereEnumerableIterator<TSource>` which was provided from the `Where` calls. Ultimately, it will end up merging the predicates:

```
public override IEnumerable<TSource> Where(Func<TSource, bool> predicate) 
{
     return new WhereEnumerableIterator<TSource>(source,
                                                 CombinePredicates(this.predicate, 
                                                                   predicate));
}

static Func<TSource, bool> CombinePredicates<TSource>(Func<TSource, bool> predicate1,
                                                      Func<TSource, bool> predicate2) 
{
    return x => predicate1(x) && predicate2(x);
}
```

But, `SingleOrDefault` itself has an overload taking a `Func<TSource, bool>` which would eliminate the need to call `Where` at all:

```
var list = GetList().SingleOrDefault(x => x.att01 == "X" && 
                                          x.att02 == "Y" && 
                                          x.att03 == "z");
```