# Linq query to match multiple parameters

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I am having a list of model which i populated with items. The below list is populated with items :-

```
List<Entry> list = new List<Entry>
{
    new Entry { EmployeeId = 1, EntryDate = '2016-11-01', InDate = '2016-11-01' },
    new Entry { EmployeeId = 1, EntryDate = '2016-11-05', InDate = '2016-11-05' },
    new Entry { EmployeeId = 2, EntryDate = '2016-11-01', InDate = '2016-11-01' }
};
```

Now I want to query a table `Entry` from database in a such a way that records should be matching with the above List with `EmployeeId` & `EntryDate` as parameter.

Entry table has same columns as in the code above.

If it was one field i can use `contains` but for multiple fields what should i do?

My results from database table should match the above List with 2 Columns matching `EmployeeId` & `EntryDate`.

Comment: You've only got a single entry in the list - it's not clear why you're using a list at all. It would help if you'd provide a [mcve]. I'd also strongly advise against using strings to store dates.

Comment: There are many entries. I have given just a example. There are more than 500 records in the List.

Comment: An example is much more helpful if it actually demonstrates what you need - in this case, just two entries would be enough to make it clear. (Using a collection initializer with object initializers would make it even clearer.) Now, you haven't told us how you're querying the table. Is this LINQ to SQL? EF? Something else? And in-memory table?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proper Linq where clauses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359980/proper-linq-where-clauses)

Comment: @JonSkeet I am using LINQ to Entities.!

Comment: You also need to explain what you mean by "matching". Does a "match" occur when *all* of the columns match *all* of the fields in *any one* of the models, or some other rule?

Comment: @TimRogers I want to match only 2 columns EmployeeId & EntryDate

Comment: I've edited your sample code to use collection and object initializers to make it *much* more readable - and valid (your previous code wouldn't actually compile, as you were declaring the same local variable multiple times, and you hadn't indented it usefully - please pay attention to this sort of thing when writing questions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Logically*, what you want is:

```
var query = db.Table.Where(e => list.Any(le => e.EmployeeId == le.EmployeeId &&
                                               e.EntryDate == le.EntryDate));
```

I don't know whether that will work with Entity Framework, but it's worth a try. (It would be fine in LINQ to Objects, for example.)

Comment: If you can express it in SQL it will work with LINQ to EF. This one won't. You could create a table-valued parameter. This is a clear sign though of ORM overuse. A stored procedure would be better

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I suggest you add an answer, then I'll delete this one.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks. I will try this code & let you know.!

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this through the `.Contains` operator and anonymous types in a way that is compatible with EF.

You need to first project your list to an anonymous type containing just those properties you want to compare.

```
var projection = from e in list 
                 select new { e.EmployeeId, e.EntryDate };
```

Then you can compare it to an identical projection in your query.

```
var query = db.Table.Where(e => projection.Contains(new { e.EmployeeId, e.EntryDate }));
```

This however generates SQL that has two parameters per item in `list`. How performant this is for 500 records, you will have to test. If this doesn't work, you can write a stored procedure with a table-valued parameter.

Comment: Thanks for Answer Tim. But in another scenario if i want to query not with table but on a List then will this work?

Comment: Do you mean "will this query work in memory as well as via SQL"? Then, yes.

Comment: I am getting error for above code as :- Delegate System.Func<Entry, int , bool> does not take 1 arguments.

Comment: This isn't working for me (EF6) - I get a System.NotSupportedException: 'Unable to create a constant value of type 'Anonymous type'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.'
What am I missing?

Comment: @Tyson This answer may be specific to SQL Server. If you're using another database, YMMV.

Comment: Strange. I'm also on SQL Server (and EF 6.2). Maybe no longer possible in recent EF versions? Or have you used this recently?