# Get total count of sql records of matched date

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, entity-framework

I'm trying to return a count of records from a database with today's date, using entity framework.  I think my query is ok, if you take a look at the screenshot record 2 is the only item out of the 3 with todays date, which is correct.

How can i return a count.  Currently its returning a bool value

Thank you

```
       Dim today = DateTime.Today.Date
       Dim todaysBuild = retrieveOrders.[Select](Function(build) build.TimeAndDate >= today).ToList()
```

[image]

EDIT:

```
 Dim todaysBuild = retrieveOrders.Where(Function(build) build.TimeAndDate >= today).ToList()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `todaysBuild` is a list. You need the count (`Integer`) of that list so add the `.Count` at the end of your code.

```
  Dim todaysBuild = retrieveOrders.[WHERE](Function(build) build.TimeAndDate >= today).ToList.Count
```

Comment: Thanks, i did try count instead of list but not both.

Comment: @AHoughton Yes, you need to add a WHERE clause. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359980/proper-linq-where-clauses

Comment: @AHoughton try replacing the [SELECT] with [WHERE]