# Select a sub-List from a List based on element values

Tags: c#, list

I have a custom object defined as follows:

```
public class Testobj
{
    public double Campo1 { get; set; }
    public int Campo2 { get; set; }
    public string Stringa1 { get; set; }
    public Testobj() { }
}
```

Then, I build a `List<Testobj>`  with these elements:

```
        List<Testobj> listobj = new List<Testobj>();
        Testobj to1 = new Testobj() { Campo1 = 0.0, Campo2 = 1, Stringa1 = "cudumar0" };
        Testobj to2 = new Testobj() { Campo1 = 1.0, Campo2 = 1, Stringa1 = "cudumar1" };
        Testobj to3 = new Testobj() { Campo1 = 2.0, Campo2 = 1, Stringa1 = "cudumar2" };
        Testobj to4 = new Testobj() { Campo1 = 3.0, Campo2 = 3, Stringa1 = "cudumar3" };
        Testobj to5 = new Testobj() { Campo1 = 4.0, Campo2 = 3, Stringa1 = "cudumar4" };
        Testobj to6 = new Testobj() { Campo1 = 5.0, Campo2 = 3, Stringa1 = "cudumar5" };
        Testobj to7 = new Testobj() { Campo1 = 6.0, Campo2 = 2, Stringa1 = "cudumar6" };
        listobj.Add(to1);
        listobj.Add(to2);
        listobj.Add(to3);
        listobj.Add(to4);
        listobj.Add(to5);
        listobj.Add(to6);
        listobj.Add(to7);
```

I now need to select from `listobj` a sublist based on its elements' values.
basycally, I need to get something like this:

```
List<Testobj> NewList = listobj.Select(...? );
```

I tried with

var query1 = listobj.Select(pr => pr.Campo2);

and also with `.Where()` or `.SelectMany()`
but I can't understand or find any clearer information on how to use these functions.
Thank you.

Comment: If you want a sub list then you need to use `Where` as that will filter.  What exactly should your sublist look like?  As an example `listoby.Where(x => x.Campo2 > 1)` would give you all the items where `Campo2` is greater than 1.

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16322/learning-about-linq  and have a look at  https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b and use https://www.linqpad.net/  to experiment. it comes with samples to play around with.

Comment: I think what you need is `GroupBy` or `ToDictionary()` Linq methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Where` is the function you're looking for. It gives you each object, and you return true or false depending on whether you want it included in your sublist or not - `list.Where(x => x.Campo2 > 100)` if you only want the elements that have the value of `Campo2` higher than 100.

`Select` is for transforming objects - if you want to just return a field on your sublist and not the entire element, you'd do `list.Select(x => x.Campo2)` to build an `IEnumerable<int>` out of all the elements of `list`.

You can combine the two to filter and transform. For example, `list.Where(x => x.Campo2 > 100).Select(x => x.Campo1)` to build an `IEnumerable<double>` made of all the `Campo1` fields in those elements that have `Campo2 > 100`.

If you need to then turn the result into a `List<>`, you can call `.ToList()` at the end of your chain of filter and transform methods.

Answer (score 1):

The line you are looking for is (Pseudo):

```
List<Testobj> filteredList = listobj.Where(x => x.Campo1.SomeProperty == 1.1m && x.Campo2 > 2 || x.Stringa1.Equals("cudumar0") ).ToList();
```

you  can remove, modify and add all kinds of conditions, based on the logic operator & and |.

Comment: `where` is not a method in C#, it's a keyword used in old Linq queries and from what I remember there's no `equals` method in a `string` in C#, there's `Equals` instead.

Comment: Ah, I didn't capitalize them. I edited it so they are. 

Still, I said we aren't a code writing service. He can just use his mind, or intellisense and fix it. I promise to put more care in my answer, when he puts more care into his question.

Comment: It's not about the question, it's about to know the language. Nowadays everyone is using IDEs which will do many things for you and many "developers" cannot even write a single line of code without it. Please put more care in every line of code you're writing.

Comment: You are seriously going to take the route that an IDE is a detriment? really?

Comment: @mrogal.ski
please also note, (Pseudo) or do you not know what that means?

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ operation to get the results. You can read more about how to use it here

[Proper Linq where clauses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359980/proper-linq-where-clauses)

The following code will return all the objects where Campo2 > 2

```
List<Testobj> NewList = listobj.Where((x => x.Campo2>2).ToList();
```