How to combine two or more fields into one LINQ expression that can be used by EF Core
I'm trying to combine two boolean filters into a single field using LINQ and Entity Framework Core:
public class Thing
{
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public bool IsAvailable => IsActive && !IsDeleted;
}

Then I would like use the IsAvailable field in my LINQ statement and for EF Core to be able to convert that statement into (Thing.IsActive = 1 AND Thing.IsDeleted = 0).
dbContext.Set<Thing>()
         .Where(x => x.IsAvailable);

Not sure where to start as LINQ expression trees are somewhat mystical at this point!

See Computed columns

If you need some flexible, check this answer

It's not elegant, but if you just want convenience, you could define an extension function something like: static IQueryable<Thing> WhereIsAvailable(this IQueryable<Thing> q) => q.Where(t => t.IsActive && !t.IsDeleted);. You could then access it with dbContext.Set<Thing>().WhereIsAvailable(). You could even make this a generic, if you define and apply an appropriate IActiveDeleted interface to your classes.

or can have mitliple where conditions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359980/proper-linq-where-clauses/6360037#6360037

NO - Wrong!
The DbSet<T> in your DbContext represent a table in your database in the non-virtual properties in T, and the relations between the tables via the virtual properties in T. You should not add functionality to T that is not in the table.
Therefore, if class Thing represents a table in your database, it should not have property IsAvailable.
The proper solution for this, would be to separate the tables from your database to the concept of being able to store data somewhere and retrieve it later, even after a restart.
This latter concept is quite often called a Repository. Users of the repository (= software,  not operators), don't know how the data is stored, and don't care. It can be stored in a database management system, or in an XML-file, maybe the data is retrieved from the internet? All they know is, that you can store items in it, and fetch them later.
A repository class hides where the data is saved DBMS, XML, ...), and how you communicate to fetch the data (SQL, Entity framework). This has several advantages.

The repository class gives you the freedom of switching how to cummunicate with your DBMS. For instance you can switch from SQL to entity framework
The repository class gives you the freedom or changing the structure of your database tables. For instance, if your first version didn't have the concept of IsDeleted, and later you decide to add it, your existing users won't have to change. Only those who want to use the new functionality need to change.
You have the freedom to change change from database to CSV-file, or any other way of storing the data. This probably won't happen often. It might be handy though, if you need some mock storage to unit test the users.
A repository class gives you the possibility to protect your database for misusage. You can create a repository(-interface) for simple users who only need to do certain queries. Super-users might need to add, delete and update records, while an Administrator might need to change the database structure.

So my proposal would be to hide that you are using entity framework by creating a repository class that gives users all the functionality that they need, without knowing that entity framework is used, or a DBMS.
You can do this by having class Thing and a special repository class corresponding to this ThingRepository. My preferenced would be to use a different namespace.
namespace MyDatabase
{
    public class Thing
    {
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
        ...
    }

    public class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Thing> Things {get; set;}
        ...
    }
}

The repository namespace also has a class Thing, or if you prefer a different name. This class hides that you are using the concept of IsDeleted
namespace Repository
{
    public class Thing
    {
        public bool IsAvailable{get; set;} // or maybe use IsActive
        ...
    }

    public class MyRepository : IDisposable
    {
        private MyDbContext DbContext {get;} = new MyDbContext(...);

        ... // TODO add other properties

Dispose will call this.DbContext.Dispose;
Simple users: only query data
Simple users may only query Things, not change them. Instead of having an IQueryable<Thing> that represents all Things, they have an IQueryable` that represents only the Things that are not deleted, or maybe Things that are not deleted and active.
public IQueryable<Thing> Things => this.DbContext
    .Where (thing => !this.IsDeleted)
    .Select(thing => new Thing
    {
        IsAvailable = thing.IsActive,
        ... // copy other properties, except IsDeleted
    })

Maybe your users only need access to Active Things:
public IQueryable<Thing> ActiveThings => this.DbContext
    .Where (thing => !this.IsDeleted && this.IsActive)
    .Select(thing => new Thing
    {
        IsAvailable = thing.IsActive,
        ... // copy other properties, except IsDeleted
    })

Come to think of it. If simple users shouldn't be able to access Unavailable Things, maybe class Thing shouldn't have property IsAvailable.
Usage: fetch only (deleted) Things that have a price more than €1000
using (MyRepository repository = new MyRepository())
{
    ICollection<Thing> expensiveThings = repository.Things
        .Where(thing => thing.Price >= 1000.0M)
        .ToList();
    this.ProcessExpensiveThings(expensiveThings);

}
Note that simple users can't access Deleted things anymore. For them there is no difference between Things that are removed from the database and Thing that have a true value for property IsDeleted. They don't even know that Things aren't really removed from the database when deleted.
Superuser: Add / Delete / Update
Only provide methods that you are certain that your users require. Too much functionality costs unnecessary development, unnecessary unit testing and it makes changes harder. It is easier to add functionality later when needed.
public void Add(Thing thing)        // this is a Repository Thing!
{
    this.DbContext.Add(new MyDatabase.Thing
    {
        Id = 0,
        IsActive = thing.IsActive,
        IsDeleted = false,
        ... // other properties copied from Repository.Thing
    }
}

Deleting a Thing is not removing it from the database, but setting IsDeleted to true. You can reuse the term Remove that people already know from entity framework, or introduce the term Delete
public void Remove(Thing thing)
{
    // TODO: exception if thing.Id == 0
    MyDatabase.Thing fetchedThing = this.DbContext.Things.Find(thing.Id);
    // TODO: exception if fetchedThing == null

    fetchedThing.IsDeleted = true;
}

Of course you need SaveChanges:
public void SaveChanges()
{
    this.DbContext.SaveChanges();
}

Usage: Add a Thing:
using (MyRepository repository = new MyRepository())
{
    Thing thing = new Thing
    {
        IsActive = true,
        Price = 1000.0M,
        ... // other properties
    }
    repository.Add(thing);
    repository.SaveChanges();
}

Fetch an expensive thing, and Remove it:
using (MyRepository repository = new MyRepository())
{
Thing expensiveThing = repository.Things
.Where(thing => thing.Price >= 1000.0M)
.FirstOrDefault();
if (expensiveThing != null)
{
repository.Remove(expensiveThing);
repository.SaveChanges();
}
}
Note: for simple users and Superusers this expensive thing is not accessible anymore. It is as if it is really removed from the storage (not using the term database, because I want the freedom to change to a CSV-file remember?)
Administator: change the structure of the database
The Administrator is the only one who knows that the repository is a relational database. If needed he has functionality to change tables, to add and remove columns and relations. Therefore the Administrator is the only one that can bypass the Repository. However, to minimize efforts when changing, consider to add methods to the Repository for the common tasks.
One common task is to remove items that were deleted a long time ago from the database. For instance, once a month he starts a procedure that removes Things that were deleted more than 6 months ago. Add to the Repository:
void RemoveItemsThatWereDeletedLongAgo()
{
    TimeSpan maxDeleteAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(183);
    DateTime deleteThreshold = DateTime.Now - maxDeleteAge;

    ICollection<Thing> thingsToRemove = this.DbContext.Things
        .Where(this => this.IsDeleted && this.DeleteTime < deleteThreshold)
        .ToList();
    this.DbContext.RemoveRange(thingsToRemove);
    this.DbContext.SaveChanges();
}

Protect users from using forbidden methods
You could make several repositories for each type of users. A simpler method would be to create interfaces:
interface IUserRepository {...}
interface ISuperUserRepository {...}
interface IAdministratorRepository {...}

class RepositoryFactory()
{
    public IUserRepository CreateUserRepository()
    {
        return new Repository();
    }
    public ISuperUserRepository CreateSuperUserRepository()
    {
        return new Repository();
    }
    public IAdministratorRepository CreateAdministratorRepository()
    {
        return new Repository();
    }
}

Of course this doesn't protect against malicious use, but you won't call the incorrect method by accident. This is not full proof, but at least it is fool proof :) If you really want safety you should work with proof of identity, like a password
